# Unable to render HTML from Markdown

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, commonmark

I am going through an online course on Laravel. This course is using the League\commonmark package for converting markdown to html.

Whenever the package is used in the app, I get:

```
 Unable to find corresponding renderer for block type League\CommonMark\Block\Element\Document
```

The app uses the following presenter to do the conversion.

```
 class PagePresenter extends AbstractPresenter
{
  protected $markdown;

  public function __construct($object, CommonMarkConverter $markdown)
  {
    $this->markdown = $markdown;
    parent::__construct($object);
  }

   public function contentHtml()
   {
    return $this->markdown->convertToHtml($this->content);
   } 
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the IoC is resolving the dependencies for `CommonMarkConverter`, specifically Environment which is instantiated with all **null** properties.

You can probably resolve this by using a Laravel specific integration: https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown

Or you can bind and instance to the service container this way:

In your `AppServiceProvider`, `register` method add this:

```
$this->app->singleton('Markdown', function ($app) {

    // Obtain a pre-configured Environment with all the CommonMark parsers/renderers ready-to-go
    $environment = \League\CommonMark\Environment::createCommonMarkEnvironment();

    // Define your configuration:
    $config = ['html_input' => 'escape'];

    // Create the converter
    return new \League\CommonMark\CommonMarkConverter($config, $environment);
});
```

Now remove `CommonMarkConverter` from your `Presenter` constructor add use `app('Markdown')`:

```
class PagePresenter extends AbstractPresenter {
  protected $markdown;

  public function __construct($object)
  {
    $this->markdown = app('Markdown');
    parent::__construct($object);
  }

   public function contentHtml()
   {
    return $this->markdown->convertToHtml($this->content);
   } 
}
```

Comment: SHould this package be a drop-in replacement for the one from the League?

Comment: The problem is with the service container ! Please check the updated answer !

Comment: I followed your instructions. Now I get "Class Markdown does not exist"

Comment: I was able to use the GrahamCampbel package. Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You just put a line in the `config/app.php` file

```
'Markdown' => GrahamCampbell\Markdown\Facades\Markdown::class,
```